# Get array value checkbox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, checkbox

I want get all value of checkbox is checked. I trying but it not working.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
    {'label': 'No', 'value': 'false'},
    {'label': 'Noo', 'value': 'false1'},
    {'label': 'Nooo', 'value': 'false2'},
    {'label': 'Nooo0', 'value': 'false3'}
]"/>
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="shift">
   <lightning:input aura:id="ab" type="checkbox" value="{! shift.value}" 
   label="Blue" name="blue" onchange="{! c.change}"/>
 </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Component.find(aura:I’d)` will return an array of elements, You need to iterate over it, and validate that their attribute `checked` is true. Then you can get the attribute values of those elements.

Comment: It's working. Thank a lot.

Comment: no prob :thumbsup:

Answer (score 0):

In component :

```
<aura:iteration var="item" items="{!v.items}">
    <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="{!item}" aura:id="mycheckbox" />
</aura:iteration>
```

In controller:

```
const cmps = component.find("mycheckbox");
if (!cmps) return;
[].concat(cmps).forEach(cmp => cmp.set("v.checked", true));
```

I have learned with help of this
[Click here to lear more of it](https://lekkimworld.com/2017/05/02/using-component-find-in-salesforce-lightning-components/)

Comment: Hi DSK, welcome to SFSE. Please note that linking to your own blog may be seen as overly self promotional, especially when you have so few other posts. Linking to it once in a while may be okay, but right now it's on 100% of your posts. Just something to think about as you add more content, try to avoid linking to blogs too much until you have a larger body of contributions to compare against.

Comment: Hi Andrian ,It is not my blog but thanks for your suggestion

Comment: That is not how you spell my name. It is just what people will assume if you link to a blog.

Comment: OK @AdrianLarson  ! Thank you may be i will not post link in my future answers

Comment: It's ok to link once in a while, you just don't want it to be in a high proportion of your total number of posts. And when that number is one, it skews things, obviously.